# Wide angle lens installed in exterior ATM has strong backlight so users are silhouetted, is there a way to change settings to get a clearer face?

Tags: outdoor, backlight, silhouette

[image: Daytime User]

There are several settings that can be changed, and WDR setting, but it doesn't always work well. I am wondering if there's a shutter speed or ISO setting that will be better at it.

Comment: What does the user manual say? Have you reached out to the camera or ATM manufacturer, to see if the camera has settings you can control, or what they suggest?

Comment: Because of the wide ranges of uses, the manual, or manufacturer don't have any specific info for the situation we are in. I can adjust minimum and maximum shutter, prefer shutter, S SNR, S SNR 2D, S SNR 3D, and AGC... all of which I don't know what they do, that's why I am asking photography people.

Comment: make the physical space around the atm interface white so that background light reflects o the faces. if you can add a light atop/behind the atm, that will also help.

Comment: 1. Add an awning, which would also increase privacy. 2. Increase ATM screen brightness so that it illuminates the customer. 3. Test if the camera is near-infrared sensitive. You could have an IR light directly in the face of the customer, and it would not be seen.

Comment: Thank you, Ideally over time all of our machines would get an enclosure which would take care of the lighting, and privacy issues. Until then I am going to test the IR light.

Answer (score -2):

Fill-in flash is your best solution for that particular photo.  You can manually open the lens to get a better shot of the subject (or use auto bracketing to take several), but the background will be all washed out.  If offered by the camera, changing where the light level is sensed, you can also adjust that so it only looks at the light level of the subject (often can be multi-point or single point -- you want single point here).  If it's a digital camera, taking multiple pictures and merging them may also work (either on-camera, if offered, or post-processing) , but you have to have a very steady hand or tripod/monopod for best results.

Comment: This is an ATM (automated teller machine) camera. They don't have fill-in flash.

Comment: OK, totally missed the ATM part. But another light source is still an option. Maybe an LED panel.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am testing an infrared light, and/or adding a LED panel to the front of the machine, bot not have it shine in the users face.